# How to dynamically change Route link in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There are 4 languages in my project. How can I make the url link change according to the language chosen by the user?
EG;

```
#EN
Route::get('/about', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('aboutview');

#DE
Route::get('/uber-uns', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('aboutview');

#TR
Route::get('/hakkimizda', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('aboutview');
```

Comment: maybe user prefix? eg {locale}/about

Comment: how do i use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reflection on your code

By the way, it is important to note that you should never declare two routes with the same name. Using your example, this is 3 routes with 3 names.

```php
Route::get('/about', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('en.aboutview'); // EN

Route::get('/uber-uns', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('de.aboutview'); // DE

Route::get('/hakkimizda', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('tr.aboutview'); // TR
```

Now can call links:

`http://example.com/about` - EN `route('en.aboutview')`
`http://example.com/uber-uns` - DE `route('de.aboutview')`
`http://example.com/hakkimizda` - TR `route('tr.aboutview')`

### Solution # 1

Use variable to will detect language.

[How to can use parameters on Route?](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-parameters) - Laravel Docs

###### routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('/{lang}/about', [Controller::class, 'aboutview'])->name('aboutview');
```

Now can call links:

`http://example.com/en/about` - EN `route('aboutview', ['lang' => 'en'])`
`http://example.com/de/about` - DE `route('aboutview', ['lang' => 'de'])`
`http://example.com/tr/about` - TR `route('aboutview', ['lang' => 'tr'])`

On your `aboutview()` function can use `$lang` variable and can return response with current language.

### Solution # 2

You can generate routes dynamically using a loop. Need use localization for colorfully names.

[Laravel Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization) - Laravel Docs

###### routes/web.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

// List of Languages
$languages = ['en', 'de', 'tr'];
// List of Routes (name => target)
$routes = [
  "aboutview" => [Controller::class, 'aboutview']
];

foreach($languages => $language) {
  foreach($routes as $name => $target) {
    $nameOnLanguage = Lang::get("routes.${name}", [], $language); // get how to call current $name of route on current $language (from /lang/$language/routes.php file)
    Route::get($nameOnLanguage, $target)->name("${language}.${name}"); // set route to /$nameOnLanguage url, can call it with route($language.$name) from Laravel
  }
}
```

###### lang/en/routes.php

```
<?php

return [
  "aboutview" => "about",
];
```

###### lang/de/routes.php

```
<?php

return [
  "aboutview" => "uber-uns",
];
```

###### lang/tr/routes.php

```
<?php

return [
  "aboutview" => "hakkimizda",
];
```

Now can call links:

`http://example.com/about` - EN `route('en.aboutview')`
`http://example.com/uber-uns` - DE `route('de.aboutview')`
`http://example.com/hakkimizda` - TR `route('tr.aboutview')`